# Line animation with label/legend - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can you add label/legend to a line animation in `matplotlib`?

```
def animate_solution(uf, u_analytical, u_numerical, ν, x, Δx, T, Δt, title=None):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0.0, 2*np.pi), ylim=(0.0, 10.0))
    plt.title(title)
    plt.xlabel('$x$')
    plt.ylabel('$u$')

    # Initialise lines
    lines = []
    for index in range(2):
        lobj = ax.plot([],[])[0]
        lines.append(lobj)    

    def init():
        lines[0].set_data(x, u_analytical)
        lines[1].set_data(x, u_numerical)
        return lines,

    def animate_method(i, uf, u_analytical, u_numerical, ν, x, Δx, Δt):
        if i > 0:
            # Calcualte the new valus
            u_numerical = burgers(u_numerical, ν, x, Δx, Δt)
            u_analytical = np.asarray([uf(i*Δt, j, ν) for j in x])

        # Update data on the lines
        lines[0].set_data(x, u_analytical)
        lines[1].set_data(x, u_numerical)

        return lines

    return animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_method, fargs=(uf, u_analytical, u_numerical, ν, x, Δx, Δt), 
                                   init_func=init, frames=int(T/Δt), interval=50, repeat=False, blit=False)
```

Using things like `lines.set_text` gives me an error when I try to call `plt.legend()` later on as it declares no label has been initialised. I have tried doing the solution of `set_texts` for a new object `texts` but it jumps everywhere and does not show the colour of the drawn lines.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. why don't you set a label when you create your lines and then call `plt.legend()`?
It would be easier if you post a MVCE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve